# HeatMap and Dendogram with 100s of records

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to plot a heatmap and dendogram with 100s of rows, but I have found the plot looks very congested and the dendogram and names are overlapping.

```
nba <- read.csv("http://datasets.flowingdata.com/ppg2008.csv", sep=",")

dat<-rbind(nba,nba,nba)

nba_matrix <- data.matrix(dat)

nba_heatmap <- heatmap(nba_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col=cm.colors(256),
                       scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
```

[image]

Is there any way to stretch the dimensions of the plot so that it will look better?

Comment: It'll need to be a big image to make all those lines readable. I'll add an answer to write it to a file.

Comment: With 500 rows, you're going to need a very big image to make it readable!

Answer (score 0):

You should write it to a file, if you aren't already. It seems heatmap puts out an image over which you have no control of the proportion (it's always square). So you need to make your canvas big to accommodate what you want!

With hundreds of rows, you are going to need to make the canvas very big to not have text overlapping.

To send it to pdf:

```
pdf("~/test.pdf", height=20, width=20)
heatmap(nba_matrix, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA, col = cm.colors(256),
        scale="column", margins=c(5,10))
dev.off()
```

Have a play with the `height` and the `width` arguments to it looks like you want. Also see `png` and associated graphics drivers.

nb: it's very important to run `dev.off()`, to switch off the graphics device. Otherwise the file write wont finish and subsequent graphics will also be sent to the file.

Comment: i used the above method but it does not work for me.

Comment: You're going to need to give more information than that.

Comment: I have edited my question to include more info about my project.

Comment: I checked the above code but names are not visible.

Comment: Are you looking at the PDF? Using the data you sent it's fine. You need to zoom in a lot because the text is so small. Small text is because there are so many rows.

Answer (score 0):

I encounted this problem as well and solved it using the code below:

```
fontsize = (10 - nrow(m))/15+1 #plus one to avoid having no font size
if (fontsize <=6){fontsize=6}
pheatmap(m, height=50, width=25, border_color = NA, fontsize_row=fontsize #of heatmp
```

This worked for me but has a limit of a few hundred items. If you have even bigger data, you need to change the height and width parameter or use a similar function to change height and width based on nrow(m) or ncol(m).

Alternatively, if you want a quick hack, you can use the package heatmaply which generates awesome html heatmaps. You open the html file in your browser and by zooming in or out within the browesr(Ctrl+ and Ctrl-) you can can change the label size easily, then click the export as png button.